# Regex for extracting Movie name from filename

Tags: regex

imagine if you will the following string:

"A Great Movie (1999) DVDRip.avi"

I am looking to extract the string "A Great Movie" from this via regex, but struggling to get the correct regex for this.

I would be using this too parse file names of various length.

thanks!

Comment: I know that this had been asked a long time ago, but I recently developed a python [library](https://github.com/divijbindlish/parse-torrent-name) for this task. It should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is designed around the .NET regex parser (may be different in other regex engines):

```
^(?<MovieName>.+)\((?<Year>\d+)\)(?<AdditionalText>[^\.]*)\.(?<Extension>[^\.]*)$
```

You can use this syntax to get out the data you want:

```
string line = "Movie Text";
Match match = Regex.Match(line);
match.Groups["MovieName"].Value;
```

You can also pull out the Year, AdditionalText, and Extension if you need it.

Comment: This is perfect for me. You have just saved me a lot of work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bracket is preceded by a space:

```
^(.+)\s\(.+
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches everything up to the first bracket

```
^([^(]+)
```

Faster (marginally) than Ben's option

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile("^([^(]+)").match("A Great Movie (1999) DVDRip.avi").groups()
('A Great Movie ',)
```